# NSData Unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I'm getting the following error when running my app:

> +[NSData dataFromBase64String:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1aff66598
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData
>   dataFromBase64String:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0x1aff66598'

The caller looks like this:

```
NSString* decodedData = [self base64Decode:encodedData];
```

And the method definitions are as follows:

```
- (NSString *)base64Decode:(NSString *)base64String {
    NSData *plainTextData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:base64String];
    NSString *plainText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plainTextData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return plainText;
}

// This is in another class
+ (NSData *)dataFromBase64String:(NSString *)aString {
    NSData *data = [aString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if( data == nil )
        return nil;
    size_t outputLength;
    void *outputBuffer = NewBase64Decode([data bytes], [data length], &outputLength);
    NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:outputBuffer length:outputLength];
    free(outputBuffer);
    return result;
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Add `#import "NSData+Base64.h"` ?

Comment: What file contains the implementation of `dataFromBase64String`?  Is it defined as a `NSData` category?  Is that file being linked into your app?

Comment: Are you aware that `NSData` already has base64 related functionality? It was added back in iOS 7.

Comment: If *This is in another class* you have to call it [AnotherClass dataFromBase64String:base64String];

Answer (score 3):

Is your implementation of 'dataFromBase64String:' in objective-C Category in a static framework or library?

If it is the case, methods in the category are not included at linking and so are not found at runtime unless you add flags '-ObjC -all_load' on OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS in Xcode.

see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1490/_index.html

Comment: Thank you! What does `-all_load` do? It seems to work with only `-ObjC` and `-all_load` doesn't seem to affect it so I'm wondering

Comment: -ObjC or -all_load force to load all code defined in Objective-C category. It forced the linker to embed code denifed in Obj-C category. Else this code is skipped and won't be available at runtime.