# Unrecognized selector sent to class runtime error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-category

I am using a third party framework containing a category on NSData and having a static method `dataUsingBase64String:` in it.
The framework got linked fine and code builds successfully. But I am getting `unrecognized selector sent to class` runtime error when this method gets called.

I have also tried adding `-ObjC`,`-all_load` flags in `OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS` of XCode with no luck..

Answer (score 3):

I guess your library is statically linked. A common problem in that is categories are not included or linked. You additionally need to add -all_load to the Other Linker Flags of the target which is using your static library.

Also check the below answers similar to your problem

Answer 1 - [NSData Unrecognized selector sent to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733291/nsdata-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-class)

Answer 2 - [Objective-C Category Causing unrecognized selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998483/objective-c-category-causing-unrecognized-selector)

Answer 3 - ["unrecognized selector sent to instance" to a static library despite ObjC flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034283/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-to-a-static-library-despite-objc-flag)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Note: I needed to add framework in this way,

[Framework Search Paths instead of adding frameworks to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2509)

Here, somehow the framework was not loaded even after adding`-Objc` or `-all_load`.

Finally, `-framework` in `OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS` did the trick for me.

Something about it from manpage,

```
-framework name[,suffix]
                 This option tells the linker to search for `name.frame-
                 work/name' the framework search path.  If the optional suffix
                 is specified the framework is first searched for the name
                 with the suffix and then without (e.g. look for `name.frame-
                 work/name_suffix' first, if not there try `name.frame-
                 work/name').
```

Answer (score 0):

If -Objc does not take effect, you can try to delete your Category from the project and drag it to the project again, and check Target membership.